# Service is not register in Eureka because of Autofac

Tags: .net-core, autofac, netflix-eureka, steeltoe

I am trying to register my .net 7 web api application to eureka server, but I am getting the following error, why?

Code Explain

I use Autofac for service registrations, I make autofac configurations in a separate dotnet 7 library project. Even though I wrote the necessary configurations to connect to the Eureka service, I get an error.

**Codes:** CoreModule

```
using Project.Services.Core.Extensions;
using Project.Services.Core.Utilities.IoC;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using StackExchange.Redis;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Steeltoe.Discovery.Client;
using Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka;

namespace Project.Services.Core.DependencyResolvers
{
    public class CoreModule : ICoreModule
    {
        public void Load(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddServiceDiscovery(o => o.UseEureka());


            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSingleton<ICacheManager, MemoryCacheManager>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDistributedCacheManager, DistributedCacheManager>();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddSingleton<Stopwatch>();

        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDependencyResolvers(new ICoreModule[]
            {
                new CoreModule()
            }, builder.Configuration);
```

**appsettings.json config**

```
  "Spring": {
    "Application": {
      "Name": "STOCK-SERVICE"
    }
  },
  "Eureka": {
    "Client": {
      "ServiceUrl": "http://localhost:867/eureka/",
      "ValidateCertificates": false,
      "ShouldRegisterWithEureka": true
    },

    // No docke instance added
    "Instance": {
      //"port": 5004,
      "NonSecurePort": 5004,
      "HostName": "localhost",
      "InstanceId": "Stock.API,Port:5004",
      "StatusPageUrlPath": "/swagger/index.html"
      //"HealthCheckUrlPath": "/api/values/healthcheck"
    }
  }
```

**Error Details**

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An exception was thrown while activating λ:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService[] -> Steeltoe.Discovery.Client.DiscoveryClientService -> λ:Steeltoe.Discovery.IDiscoveryClient -> λ:Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient -> Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaApplicationInfoManager.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.RegistrationPipelineInvokeMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<BuildPipeline>b__1(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Pipeline.ResolvePipeline.Invoke(ResolveRequestContext ctxt)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.InvokePipeline(ResolveRequest request, DefaultResolveRequestContext requestContext)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) 




DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaInstanceOptions], Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'EurekaApplicationInfoManager'.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: It's that the whole exception? No inner exception also listed?

Comment: Can you @TravisIllig check this repo -> https://github.com/xXAvoraXx/SteeltoeProject

I have prepared a small demo version for you to review.

Comment: @TravisIllig Did you have a chance to review it? I just added a commit to the project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to offer free consulting and debugging hours. I wish I did. If that's what it will require, perhaps someone else in the community can jump in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't find how to solve the problem. At a glance, this looks like either the LoggerFactory isn't registered with AutoFac or there is an issue with retrieving the options. @TravisIllig

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: It gives an error when run with docker-compose, but no error occurs when run with IIS.

Comment: solution -> https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/issues/1186#issuecomment-1739365575